# How to read zip file from S3 public bucket without Aws key and secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

I have a use case where I have to read a ZIP file and pass it to the creation of lambda as a template.
Now I want to read zip file from a S3 public bucket. How can I read the file from the public bucket?

S3 bucket zip file where I am reading is https://lambda-template-code.s3.amazonaws.com/LambdaTemplate.zip

```
const zipContents = 'https://lambda-template-code.s3.amazonaws.com/LambdaTemplate.zip';

    var params = {
        Code: { 
               // here at below I have to pass the zip file reading it from the S3 public bucket
               ZipFile: zipContents,
        },
        FunctionName: 'testFunction', /* required */
        Role: 'arn:aws:iam::149727569662:role/ROLE', /* required */
        Description: 'Created with tempalte',
        Handler: 'index.handler',
        MemorySize: 256,
        Publish: true,
        Runtime: 'nodejs12.x',
        Timeout: 15,
        TracingConfig: {
            Mode: "Active"
           }
      };
      lambda.createFunction(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      });
```

The above code gives error `Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again`

How can I read the URL file? And pass it in the `params`

Can anyone help me here

Comment: If you read the docs for CreateFunction, you'll see that ZipFile is a blob, not a URL to a ZIP file. Does this work if you use `S3Key: zipContents` in place of `ZipFile: zipContents`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [createFunction docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html) and specifically the [Code docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_FunctionCode.html), you can see that `ZipFile` expects

> The base64-encoded contents of the deployment package. AWS SDK and AWS CLI clients handle the encoding for you.

and not a URL of where it is. Instead, you need to use `S3Bucket` and `S3Key`.

It is not clear from the docs that public buckets are allowed for this purpose, but the docs do say

> An Amazon S3 bucket in the same AWS Region as your function. The bucket can be in a different AWS account.